# Undo/redo memento pattern c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, undo, redo, memento

I am trying to implement the Undo/Redo functionality for the nodes of a tree in C# (treeView component). I have used the memento pattern but I am having trouble with the Redo part. I cannot see where my logic is flawed. Here are some snaps of the code

```
    private List<Memento> _mementoStateList= new List<Memento>();
    private List<Memento> _undoStateList= new List<Memento>();
    public Memento Memento { get{return null;}
        set{_mementoStateList.Add(value);} }

    public Memento Undo()
    {
        if (!_mementoStateList.Any()) return null;
        Memento m = _mementoStateList.Last();
        _undoStateList.Add(m);
        _mementoStateList.Remove(m);
        return m;
    }

    public Memento Redo()
    {
        if (!_undoStateList.Any()) return null;
        Memento m = _undoStateList.Last();
        _mementoStateList.Add(m);
        _undoStateList.Remove(m);
        return m;
    }
```

In my form, before deleting a node I am calling the SaveMemento() method which creates a new Memento object representing the current state. The object is added to the _mementoStateList.

When Undo-ing and Redo-ing an action, I call the above Undo() and Redo() method.

I assume I am not saving the states in the right moment?
Any input is highly appreciated!

Comment: When you set a new memento, you should reset your undo-state-list... Else that list could get a very weird contents is certain use-cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider to implement Undo/redo using [Command](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Command/) pattern, while with [Memento](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Memento/) if you need to store a lot of states(in fact the question is how many undo actions you will support) then implementation can be heavy.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the memento you must do a deep clone of the object tree, otherwise the memento will just be a reference to the current state. In that case any change to the state will reflect to all mementos, ruining any attempt to keep a history of prior (or potential future) states.

Comment: I am indeed cloning the root element and storing it as a TreeNode.

Comment: I think deep cloning is a pain. Command patter is the perfect partner of memento pattern.

Comment: That may not suffice, because from the root node the references to deeper nodes still point to the current state. If you just clone the root, that's a shallow clone at most. For a deep clone, you must visit the tree and clone all objects (including boxed integers if you have any) in the process. The only exception are strings, which are intrinsically created on change.

Comment: @jlvaquero I agree, also storing state means allocating a lot of memory. This may not be feasible in some cases, while command pattern is far more efficient but requires deeper insight into what you're doing. A drawback is that for actions that do not have and inverse action, on UNDO you have to redo all prior commands up to a full state-save to reestablish the correct state. So commands in memento is perfect if every action has an inverse action, otherwise it gets complicated, too.